# Is there an equivalent to Perls' split() function in C?

Tags: c, split, strtok

I'm trying to split real numbers in a C program using the decimal point as the delimter such that such that say, 1234.56 yields

(int) whole_num = 1234
(int) fraction = 56

Any ideas how I can go about doing this? Its been a loooong while since I mucked around with C, see? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void split( double num, int& whole_number, double& fraction) {
    fraction = modf(num, &whole_number);
}
```

This works since modf takes the integer part of the double and returns the fractional part.

Comment: -1 Use modf if you're actually decomposing a floating-point number.

Comment: Wow, thanks Daniel! That was quick- and certainly cleaner than some of the other solutions I pulled up online using strtok(). I'm curious to see what others come up with.

Comment: Why not just fractional_part = modf(num, &integral_part) ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to split a string.

`strtok_r` and your favorite string-to-num function like `strtol`

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with an actual floating-point number, as opposed to a string representation of such, you should use [`modf`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/modf.html) for splitting out the integral and fractional parts.

Perl's `split` splits by regex, so to replicate full functionality you'd need a regex library. For general string-splitting, you may be able to use [`strtok`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html), but because it changes the string in-place, `strtok_r` (described on the same page) is recommended instead.